# Searching the Youtube Playlist in android app

Tags: android, youtube, android-recyclerview

I followed [this](https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist) sample to show youtube videos in Android App
I am stuck at implementing a search bar in it. How can I implement the logic of the Search Bar? I tried to implement Searchable Interface but failed at the setup part.

This is the Adapter:

```
public class PlaylistCardAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaylistCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
   .......

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


public PlaylistCardAdapter(PlaylistVideos playlistVideos, YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.LastItemReachedListener lastItemReachedListener) {
    mPlaylistVideos = playlistVideos;
    mListener = lastItemReachedListener;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public PlaylistCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflate a card layout
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.youtube_video_card, parent, false);
    // populate the viewholder
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (mPlaylistVideos.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    final Video video = mPlaylistVideos.get(position);
    final VideoSnippet videoSnippet = video.getSnippet();

    holder.mTitleText.setText(videoSnippet.getTitle());

    if (mListener != null) {
        // get the next playlist page if we're at the end of the current page and we have another page to get
        final String nextPageToken = mPlaylistVideos.getNextPageToken();
        if (!isEmpty(nextPageToken) && position == mPlaylistVideos.size() - 1) {
            holder.itemView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mListener.onLastItem(position, nextPageToken);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPlaylistVideos.size();
}

private boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the link to the fragment class - [link](https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/akoscz/youtube/YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.java)

Comment: how should the search work? Filtering the ArrayList?

Comment: Tipo of advice:  I haven't really looked into the project. But be careful of what api key you are bundling in the app. Anything in the app can evetually be reversersed engineered.

Comment: Yes I want to search the Playlist videos once fetched locally. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solutions consists of having two copies of the playlist in the adapter. One will be the complete original list passed to the adapter, and the other a list that will have the items that result selected from applying the search.

The second list is the one that will be updated when the user submits the search, and will also be the one shown in the Recycler View.

In the following example:

`Xxxxx` would be a playlist item in your case.

`originalData` keeps the complete list of items.

`setData()` is called to update the RecyclerView with a new list of items.

`setSearchText()` is called to pass in the text to filter the recycler view items.
This can be called with the complete text to search, or each time the user releases a key when typing into an EditText for example.

`refreshData()` calls `applySearch()` to do the filtering and then updates the RecyclerView on screen with the found items.

```
public class XxxxxsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<XxxxxsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Xxxxx> data;
    private ArrayList<Xxxxx> originalData;
    private Context context;
    private String searchText;

    public XxxxxsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Xxxxx> data) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.originalData = new ArrayList<>();
        if(this.data != null) {
            this.originalData.addAll(this.data);
        }
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Xxxxx> data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.originalData.clear();
        if (data != null) {
            this.originalData.addAll(this.data);
        }
        refreshData();
    }

    public void setSearchText(String searchText){
        this.searchText = searchText;
        refreshData();
    }


    private void applySearch(){
        if(data != null) {
            if (searchText != null && !searchText.equals("")) {
                ArrayList<Xxxxx> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                tmp.addAll(data);
                data.clear();
                for (Xxxxx xxxxx : tmp) {
                    if (xxxxx.getNombre().toUpperCase().contains(searchText.toUpperCase())) {
                        data.add(xxxxx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void refreshData(){
        this.applySearch();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    ...

}
```